# React Native Navigation: best way to organize component references in tab navigators nested in a stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

In my React Native app I have a stack navigator called `StackNavigator` that contains two tab navigators `TabNavigator1` and `TabNavigator2`. `TabNavigator1` contains the screens `TabNavigator1_Screen1` and `TabNavigator1_Screen2`, and `TabNavigator1` contains `TabNavigator2_Screen1`, and `TabNavigator2_Screen2`.
From all four of those screens, the user needs to be able to navigate to various other screens, `Screen1`, `Screen2`, and `Screen3`.

I'm using `react-navigation@4.x`

**What I Want To Know:**

Where is the best place to put references to `Screen1`, `Screen2`, and `Screen3`? The only place I know I can add them is when defining `StackNavigator`. So I would do

```
createStackNavigator(
  {
    TabNavigator1,
    TabNavigator2,
    TabNavigator1_Screen1,
    TabNavigator1_Screen2,
    TabNavigator2_Screen1,
    TabNavigator2_Screen2,
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
    Screen3,
    Screen4,
  }
)
```

and then in `TabNavigator1` and `TabNavigator1` pass their navigation prop to the screens with

```
screenProps={{
  navigation: this.props.navigation
}}
```

so that `TabNavigator1_Screen1` can navigate to `Screen1` with `this.props.screenProps.navigation.navigate('Screen1')`.

Is there a way I can organize all those screen references so that I define specific screens that screens in `TabNavigator1` can navigate to, and others that screens in `TabNavigator1` can navigate to?